# How to merge output text if object has same string_id

Tags: javascript, arrays

For example if I have an array object like this

```
let arr = [
   {
      id: 'stringId_01',
      model1: {
            name: 'course_name1',
            time: '10:00'
        }
   },
   {
        id: 'stringId_02',
        model1: {
            name: 'course_name2',
            time: '11:00'
        }
    },
    {
        id: 'stringId_01',
        model1: {
            name: 'course_name3',
            time: '09:00'
        }
    },
    {
        id: 'stringId_03',
        model1: {
            name: 'course_name_01',
            time: '10:00'
        }
    }
 ]
```

I try to get the output in a text so I can use node scheduler to send email notification.

I can get the output in individual text

```
   output
   - course_name1 10:00
   - course_name2 11:00
   - course_name3 09:00
   - course_name_01 10:00
```

However, in that case user with stringId_01 will receive two separate email notification.

How I can get the output text like this so user with stringId_01 will receive one email notification

```
   output
   - course_name1 10:00, course_name3 09:00
   - course_name2 11:00
   - course_name_01 10:00
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the unique ids with [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and loop through the resulting array by using [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) .

Inside the loop, use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get the items in the array with the same `id`. [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) is used to get the desired output string.

```js
let arr=[{id:"stringId_01",model1:{name:"course_name1",time:"10:00"}},{id:"stringId_02",model1:{name:"course_name2",time:"11:00"}},{id:"stringId_01",model1:{name:"course_name3",time:"09:00"}},{id:"stringId_03",model1:{name:"course_name_01",time:"10:00"}}];


const uniqueIDs = [...new Set(arr.map(e => e.id))]
uniqueIDs.forEach(e => {
  const str = '- ' + arr.filter(f => f.id == e).map(e => e.model1.name + ' ' + e.model1.time).join(', ')
  console.log(str)
})
```

If you want it as one string:

```js
let arr=[{id:"stringId_01",model1:{name:"course_name1",time:"10:00"}},{id:"stringId_02",model1:{name:"course_name2",time:"11:00"}},{id:"stringId_01",model1:{name:"course_name3",time:"09:00"}},{id:"stringId_03",model1:{name:"course_name_01",time:"10:00"}}];

const uniqueIDs = [...new Set(arr.map(e => e.id))]
const str = uniqueIDs.map(e => '- ' + arr.filter(f => f.id == e).map(e => e.model1.name + ' ' + e.model1.time).join(', ')).join('\n')
console.log(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this this way:

```js
var course={}
for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
   var comma ="";
   if(course[arr[i].id]=== undefined)
   {
       course[arr[i].id]="- "  ;
   }
   else
   {
     comma=", "  ;
   }
   course[arr[i].id]+=comma+(arr[i].model1.name + " " +arr[i].model1.time) ;
}
var result=""
for (var prop in course) {
  result+=course[prop] +"\n" ;
}
console.log(result);
console.log(course);
```